# Ionic/Firebase (Android) - signInWithCredentials does not work correctly

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic3

I made a simple login system with Ionic 3 and Firebase database. I went through the hell doing this, because something what work on browser not necessarly work on android. Anyways I got this working, but there is couple of bugs(?) that I don't know how to solve.

I will start with some code, so you should know what i am talking about:

My login with facebook method looks like this:

```
async nativeFbLogin(): Promise<void> {
  this.toast.create({ message: "ZAczynam", duration: 2000 }).present();
  return this.fb.login(["email", "public_profile"]).then(res => {
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      res.authResponse.accessToken
    );
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
      .then(res => {
        this.makeToast(JSON.stringify(res));
      });
  });
}
```

and google login:

```
async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const gplususer = await this.gplus.login({
      webClientId:
        "blahblah",
      offline: true
    });

    return await this.fire.auth
      .signInWithCredential(
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplususer.idToken)
      )
      .then(r => {
        this.makeToast("zalogowano");
      });
  } catch (err) {
    this.toast.create({ message: "error" + err, duration: 3000 }).present();
  }
}
```

As you can see I use `signInWithCredential` method because only this works on andoroid (as mentioned in number of forums).

So bugs what I am facing:

1. I can login with facebook and google+ email addresses are the same - it does not work in browser when using `sign in with popup` so why it works in this case? In browser when i register from google+ and then i try to log in with fb with the same email address i get error like 'there is an account with this email addres please choose correct login provider'.
2. I cannot choose account to login with google or facebook - what annoys me the most, because what if user (like me) have two or more fb and google accounts on the same phone?

Could I ask for any advice with solving this problems?

Comment: maybe it's something related to allowed origins in your api settings both in google and facebook

Comment: also check the console for 'cordova not available' or something in the console, if so, means some plugins not supported for the browser